# How to create nested dict with parent children hierachy for streamlit_tree_select from dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, streamlit

To use [`streamlit_tree_select`](https://github.com/Schluca/streamlit_tree_select) I need to convert a dataframe to its expected structure.

I guess to achieve the goal I could use `pandas.groupby('parkey')` to group the children, but I'm not sure how to apply this to the appropriate parents while iterating the groups.

The dataframe holding categories:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
  {"idnr": 1,"parkey": 0,"descr": "A","info":"string"},
  {"idnr": 2,"parkey": 0,"descr": "B","info":"string"},
  {"idnr": 3,"parkey": 2,"descr": "B B 1","info":"string"},
  {"idnr": 4,"parkey": 3,"descr":"B B B 1","info":"string"},
  {"idnr": 5,"parkey": 3,"descr":"B B B 2","info":"string"}
]
```

The expected output:

```
output = [
  {"idnr": 1,"parkey": 0,"descr": "A","info":"string"},
  {"idnr": 2,"parkey": 0,"descr": "B","info":"string","children":[
         {"idnr": 3,"parkey": 2,"descr": "B B 1","info":"string","children":[
            {"idnr": 4,"parkey": 3,"descr":"B B B 1","info":"string"},
            {"idnr": 5,"parkey": 3,"descr":"B B B 2","info":"string"}
         ]}
      ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to pre-process the data, forming a dict with the children of each of the parents. You can then process the `0` property of this dict, recursively adding children from the dict to the appropriate `children` array:

```py
def add_child(tree, child):
    key = child['parkey']
    tree[key] = tree.get(key, []) + [child]

parents = dict()
for child in data:
    add_child(parents, child)
```

Output:

```
{
 0: [
  {'idnr': 1, 'parkey': 0, 'descr': 'A', 'info': 'string'},
  {'idnr': 2, 'parkey': 0, 'descr': 'B', 'info': 'string'}
 ],
 2: [
  {'idnr': 3, 'parkey': 2, 'descr': 'B B 1', 'info': 'string'}
 ],
 3: [
  {'idnr': 4, 'parkey': 3, 'descr': 'B B B 1', 'info': 'string'},
  {'idnr': 5, 'parkey': 3, 'descr': 'B B B 2', 'info': 'string'}
 ]
}
```

Now you can iterate the entries in `parents[0]`, recursively adding children as you go:

```
def add_children(tree, parents):
    for child in tree:
        # any children
        idnr = child['idnr']
        if idnr in parents:
            # add the children
            child['children'] = parents[idnr]
            add_children(child['children'], parents)

output = parents[0]
add_children(output, parents)
```

Output:

```
[
  {'idnr': 1, 'parkey': 0, 'descr': 'A', 'info': 'string'},
  {'idnr': 2, 'parkey': 0, 'descr': 'B', 'info': 'string', 'children': [
      {'idnr': 3, 'parkey': 2, 'descr': 'B B 1', 'info': 'string', 'children': [
          {'idnr': 4, 'parkey': 3, 'descr': 'B B B 1', 'info': 'string'},
          {'idnr': 5, 'parkey': 3, 'descr': 'B B B 2', 'info': 'string'}
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Notes:**

1. The `add_children` routine modifies the `data` list as it relies on references to work. If you don't want to that, make a copy of `data` first or change the `add_child` code to make copies when assigning `child` values.
2. You could combine `add_child` and `add_children`, however by splitting the task it means that `data` does not have to be sorted by `parkey`.

Comment: @Hedgehog, apologies for the snafu on the code, I made some edits as I was typing the answer and thought I had left it consistent but obviously should have quit the interpreter and restarted to ensure I had a clean slate. Anyway, the `return` statements are not required as the tree gets modified inside the functions; what was wrong was the line `parents = add_child(parents, child)` which should simply have been `add_child(parents, child)`

Comment: Thanks again and no problem, it took me a few thinking loops until I came to the same conclusion. In any case, your breakdown into the two steps was very helpful and I was able to adapt the approach for determining the number of articles for the respective parents.